# Trying to access the HTML5 email validation client-side

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just trying to do a simple email validation, I have an email input that is just

```
<input type='email' id="user_email">
```

and I'm trying to call on it with Javascript using

```
document.getElementById('user_email').addEventListener('invalid', function() {
    console.log('Invalid Email');
})
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, I've tried googling but found nothing. Thanks!

I'm just trying to use HTML5 validation on the email to change a P elements text to something like, 'Invalid email format'.

Answer (score 0):

Add id to input ?

```
<input type='email' id='user_email' />
```

Comment: That was just a quick example of what I meant, I do have that on my original

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the entire

```
document.getElementById('user_email').addEventListener('invalid', function() {
    console.log('Invalid Email');
})
```

to

```
document.getElementById('user_email').checkValidity();
```